# PHP Web Framework that doesn't need CLI on live server?

Tags: php, frameworks

I am looking for suggestions for a PHP Web framework that doesn't need CLI access on the production server.  For various reasons that aren't relevant, there is absolutely no shell access to the production server of the site I'm working on, neither by developers nor admin staff (after initial setup).  Interaction is FTP only.

Now on the development server, CLI is just fine, so things like CLI-based scaffolding generators are great, but not things needed to deploy and update on live.

Let me give an example of what I mean with the two frameworks I know a bit:

CodeIgniter needs no CLI - just moving files by FTP is enough (and CI is probably what I'll use if I don't find anything else, but I'm concerned about its future).

Laravel, OTOH, really relies on composer and artisan.  Adding classes often calls for a composer dump auto load command, and migrations rely on artisan commands.  Yes, I can skip migrations, but I will need to add classes as functionality is added over the application's life cycle.  I'm sure there are ways around it, but the point is to use the framework, not work against it...

So, are there other good frameworks that meet this criteria?

Thanks,
Juliean.

Comment: While its true most frameworks have a lot of overhead with composer and other mostly not necessary bloating for PHP development, all that is really required by the production area is the initial setup. Everything else should be tested and implemented in your testing/development area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to deploy most frameworks without cli access, just do all the build steps on your local machine, eg composer installs etc and ftp up the result. Most migration tools can dump out the SQL that needs to be run, then you can run that against the db manually.

Think about having to deploy to 10 servers, you wouldnt want to be logging into each one manually to run commands.